# Check a string for bad words?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way to test string for certain words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801486/efficient-way-to-test-string-for-certain-words)

I want to check if a string contains any of these words: *ban, bad, user, pass, stack, name, html*.

If it contains any of the words I need to echo the number of bad words

```
str = 'Hello my name is user';
```

Comment: For what do you need this? "ban" and such are usually no "bad words".

Comment: Watch out, you're headed for [a clbuttic mistake](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx).

Comment: As you go forward with this, please only filter upon display.  Leave the data in your DB clean, unless for performance reasons you need to filter ahead of time.  That way if you do make a "clbuttic error", it is no big deal.  Plus, the "adults" on your board could eventually have a setting to see everything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
$badWords = array("ban","bad","user","pass","stack","name","html");

$string = "Hello my name is user.";

$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                $string, 
                $matches
              );

if ($matchFound) {
  $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
  foreach($words as $word) {
    echo "<li>" . $word . "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

This creates an array of banned words, and uses a [regular expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) to find instances of these words:

- `\b` in the Regex indicates a word boundary (i.e. the beginning or end of a word, determined by either the beginning/end of the string or a non-word character). This is done to prevent ["clbuttic" mistakes](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) - i.e. you don't want to ban the word "banner" when you only want to match the word "ban".
- The [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function creates a single string containing all your banned words, separated by a pipe character, which is the `or` operator in the Regex.
- The `implode` portion of the Regex is surrounded with parentheses so that [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will capture the banned word as the match.
- The `i` modifier at the end of the Regex indicates that the match should be case-sensitive - i.e. it will match each word regardless of capitalization - "Ban, "ban", and "BAN" will all match against the word "ban" in the `$badWords` array.

Next, the code checks if any matches were found. If there are, it uses [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to ensure only one instance of each word is reported, and then it outputs the list of matches in an unordered list.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This is great when you don't have many 'bad words'. I have 3000 words, and the regular expression doesn't work because it is too large.

Comment: If a word match doesnt rely on the case of the word then it is said to be "Case insensitive", but apart from that thanks!

Comment: What flag should i use if the word have accent (for spanish) for example: avión ???

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want.

```
function teststringforbadwords($string,$banned_words) {
    foreach($banned_words as $banned_word) {
        if(stristr($string,$banned_word)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$string = "test string";
$banned_words = array('ban','bad','user','pass','stack','name','html');

if (!teststringforbadwords($string,$banned_words)) {
    echo 'string is clean';
}else{
    echo 'string contains banned words';
}
```

Comment: A couple issues here - 1) this is vulnerable to ["clbuttic" issues](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) where you'll accidentally ban the words "banner" and "namesake" when trying to look for "ban" and "name", and 2) `stristr` returns the position index of the match, but because it is zero-based, a match at the very beginning of the string looks the same as "false". You need to update the code to explicitly check that `stristr` returns `false` not just `0` - i.e. `if(stristr($string,$banned_word) === FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

- The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct
  word "web" is matched, and not a word partial like "webbing" or "cobweb"

  if (preg_match("/\bweb\b/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
          echo "A match was found.";
      } else {
          echo "A match was not found.";
      }

  ```
  if (preg_match("/\bweb\b/i", "PHP is the website scripting language of choice.")) {
      echo "A match was found.";
  } else {
      echo "A match was not found.";
  }
  ```

This is your best bet. As stated at the beginning you can control your regex.

This is directly from  [php.net](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_words($text) {
    $text=$text;
    $bad_words = file('bad_words.txt');
    $bad = explode(" | ",$bad_words[0]);
    $b = '/\W' . implode('\W|\W', $bad) . '\W/i';
    if(preg_match($b, $text)){
        echo $text ." - Contain Bad words!";
        # - other function here
    }
    else{
        echo $text ." - Not containing bad words :D";
        # - other function here
    }

}
# - Example
check_words('He is good');
```

Hope this can help.. you can put all the bad words in *bad_words.txt* file.

Arrange the bad words in txt as:

```
bad_words1 | bad_words2 | bad_words3 | bad_words4 ...
```

Note: you can also put something like:

```
bad words 1 | bad words 2 | bad words 3
```

as long as it is in the "|" format.

Comment: `\W` what for ? it works when i removed all `\W`

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_words($text) {
  $text=$text;
  $bad_words = file('bad_words.txt');
  $bad = explode(" | ",$bad_words[0]);
  $b = '/\W' . implode('\W|\W', $bad) . '\W/i';

  if(preg_match($b, $text)){
    echo $text ." - Contain Bad words!"; other function here
  } else {
    echo $text ." - Not containing bad words :D";
    // other function here
  }
}
```

Example: `check_words('He is good');`

This works well although anything after the final `/` does not seem to get checked, e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/thisbit`, `thisbit` seems not to get checked for bad words.

It does work again how ever if it is typed like this: `http://www.mysite.com/thisbit/`, with the trailing `/`.

Not sure if this can be fixed or not.