# Efficient way to test string for certain words

Tags: php, string

I have a bunch of banned words and want to check if string A contains any of these words.

For example:

```
$banned_words = "dog cat horse bird mouse monkey blah blah2 blah3 "; //etc
$string_A = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
```

How can I efficiently check to see if any of the words in the string match up with any of the words in the banned words list?

Comment: This has been done thousands of times over. Search google or stackoverflow for 'php bad word' or something and you'll find a dozen different solutions. e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615146/check-a-string-for-bad-words Cheers

Comment: thanks, the phrase 'bad word' is unfamiliar to me in a programming aspect. I would have googled if I knew. Cheers

Comment: No problem, that's what I figured. Cheers

Comment: @dukevin: Well, there's "banned word" too, which you used yourself in the question several times. Programming has nothing to do with these English constructions!

Comment: I know of several ways to do this, I also wanted the most efficient, hence my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('~\b(' . str_replace(' ', '|', $banned_words) . ')\b~', $string_A)) {
    // there is banned word in a string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better if the `$banned_w` would be an array?

Then you could `explode()` the string you want to check for banned words, then for every exploded piece use `in_array()` to check if it's a banned word.

Edit:
You could use: [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) for the comparisons, if one modifies the bad word a bit.

Comment: Scanning a string N times (for each word) isn't efficient, I suppose

Comment: I had that in mind initially but I didn't think searching through an array of size [insert big number here] for each string would be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
$badwords = array('dog','cat','horse','bird','mouse','monkey');
$content= "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
$content = str_replace($badwords, 'has_badwords' $content);
if (strpos($content, 'has_badwords') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a whole lot easier to create an array of banned words and then use `str_replace` with that array, like so:

```
$banned_words = array('dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'bird', 'mouse', 'monkey', 'blah', 'blah2', 'blah3');
$string_A = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
echo str_replace($banned_words, "***", $string_A);
```

Will output: `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy ***`

Answer (score 0):

I just developed a function that can filter out the bad words:

```
function hate_bad($str)
{
    $bad=array("shit","ass");
    $piece=explode(" ",$str);
    for($i=0;$i < sizeof($bad); $i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<sizeof($piece);$j++)
        {
            if($bad[$i]==$piece[$j])
            {
                $piece[$j]=" ***** ";
            }
        }
    }

    return $piece;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$str=$_REQUEST['bad'];// here bad is the name of tex field<br/><br/>
$good=hate_bad($str);  <br/>  

if(isset($_REQUEST['filter']))// 'filter' name of button
{
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($good);$i++)
    {<br/>
        echo $good[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_ireplace, to check for bad words or phrases. This can be done **in a single line** of PHP code without the need for  nested loops or regex as follows:

```
$banstring = ($string != str_ireplace($badwords,"XX",$string))? true: false;
```

This approach has the added benefit of being case insensitive. To see this in action, you could implement the check as follows:

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
$badwords = array('dog','cat','horse','bird','mouse','monkey');
$banstring = ($string != str_ireplace($badwords,"XX",$string))? true: false;
if ($banstring) {
    echo 'Bad words found';
} else {
    echo 'No bad words in the string';
}
```

If the list of bad words is a string rather than an array (as in the question), then the string can be turned into an array as follows:

```
$banned_words = "dog cat horse bird mouse monkey"; //etc
$badwords = explode(" ", $banned_words);
```