# PHP code to create a negative word dictionary and search if a post has negative words

Tags: php, search, sentiment-analysis, words

I'm trying to develop a PHP application where it takes comments from users and then match the string to check if the comment is positive or negative. I have  list of negative words in negative.txt file. If a word is matched from the word list, then I want a simple integer counter to increment by 1. I tried the some links and created the a code to check if the comment has is negative or positive but it is only matching the last word of the file.Here's the code what i have done.

```
    <?php 
    function teststringforbadwords($comment) 
    {
      $file="BadWords.txt";
      $fopen = fopen($file, "r");
      $fread = fread($fopen,filesize("$file"));
      fclose($fopen);
      $newline_ele = "\n";
      $data_split = explode($newline_ele, $fread);
      $new_tab = "\t";
      $outoutArr = array();
      //process uploaded file data and push in output array
      foreach ($data_split as $string)
      {
          $row = explode($new_tab, $string);
          if(isset($row['0']) && $row['0'] != ""){
              $outoutArr[] = trim($row['0']," ");
          }
      }
      //---------------------------------------------------------------
        foreach($outoutArr as $word) {

        if(stristr($comment,$word)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))
    {
        $comments = $_REQUEST["comments"];
        if (teststringforbadwords($comments)) 
        {
            echo 'string is clean';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'string contains banned words';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Link Tried : [Check a string for bad words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615146/check-a-string-for-bad-words)

Comment: why your storing $row['0'] only why not others index words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `strtolower` function around both your `$comments` and your input from the file. That way if someone spells `STUPID`, instead of `stupid`, the code will still detect the bad word.

I also added `trim` to remove unnecessary and disruptive whitespace (like newline).

Finally, I changed the way how you check the words.  I used a `preg_match` to split about all whitespace so we are checking only full words and don't accidentally ban incorrect strings.

```
<?php 
    function teststringforbadwords($comment) 
    {
      $comment = strtolower($comment);
      $file="BadWords.txt";
      $fopen = fopen($file, "r");
      $fread = strtolower(fread($fopen,filesize("$file")));
      fclose($fopen);
      $newline_ele = "\n";
      $data_split = explode($newline_ele, $fread);
      $new_tab = "\t";
      $outoutArr = array();
      //process uploaded file data and push in output array
      foreach ($data_split as $bannedWord)
      {
          foreach (preg_split('/\s+/',$comment) as $commentWord) {
              if (trim($bannedWord) === trim($commentWord)) {
                  return false;
              }
          }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your storing `$row['0']` only why not others index words. So problem is your ignoring some of word in text file.

`Some suggestion`

1) Insert the text in text file `one by one` i.e new line like this so you can access easily explode by newline to avoiding multiple explode and loop.

```
 Example: sss.txt
 ...
 bad
 stupid
 ...
 ...
```

2) Apply trim and lowercase function to  both comment and bad string.

*Hope it will work as expected*

```
function teststringforbadwords($comment) 
{
  $file="sss.txt";
  $fopen = fopen($file, "r");
  $fread = fread($fopen,filesize("$file"));
  fclose($fopen);

  foreach(explode("\n",$fread) as $word) 
  {

    if(stristr(strtolower(trim($comment)),strtolower(trim($word))))
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: JyoThi, i am getting a Warning if the string has good or neutral words

Comment: Warning: stristr(): Empty needle in C:\xampp\htdocs\sentiment\searchbadwords1.php on line 46
string is clean

Comment: Hey i got the solution to the problem it was a blank line at the end of BadWords.txt. Ty for your help.